# XML Reading wrong tabs

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to read a xml where i need to get the respective segments from each road, and put the information in other classes.

Here is the XML file:

```
<section_list>  
 <road_section begin="n0" end="n1">
     <road>"E01"</road>
     <wind_speed>3 m/s</wind_speed>
      <segment_list>
         <segment id="01">
               <height>100</height>
              <number_vehicles>20</number_vehicles>
         </segment>
         <segment id="02">
              <height>148</height>
              <number_vehicles>20</number_vehicles>
         </segment>
      </segment_list>
 </road_section>
 <road_section begin="n0" end="n2">
     <road>"E01"</road>
     <wind_speed>3 m/s</wind_speed>
        <segment_list>
            <segment id="03">
                <height>100</height>
                <number_vehicles>100</number_vehicles>
            </segment>
         </segment_list>
 </road_section> 
</section_list>
```

What happen when I run the program is that, for each road he prints all the segments, for example for the road 'EO1' the program prints the 3 segments when he should only print the segments id=01 and id=02.

And here is my Java code:

```
NodeList listSection = doc.getElementsByTagName("road_section");
for (int temp = 0; temp < listSection.getLength(); temp++) {
    Node nNode = listSection.item(temp);
    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

        System.out.println("Begin : " + eElement.getAttribute("begin") + "\tEnd: " + eElement.getAttribute("end"));
        System.out.println("road : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("road").item(0).getTextContent().replaceAll("\"", ""));
        System.out.println("wind_speed : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("wind_speed").item(0).getTextContent().trim().replaceAll("m/s", ""));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
        NodeList listaSegmentos = eElement.getElementsByTagName("segment_list").item(i).getChildNodes();
        for (int j = 0; j < listaSegmentos.getLength(); j++) {
            Node nodeseg = listaSegmentos.item(cont);
            if (nodeseg.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element el = (Element) nodeseg;
                System.out.println("\nSegment id : " + el.getAttribute("id"));
                System.out.println("height : " + el.getElementsByTagName("height").item(0).getTextContent().replaceAll("\"", ""));
                System.out.println("number_vehicles : " + el.getElementsByTagName("number_vehicles").item(0).getTextContent().trim());

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getElementsByTagName("segment_list")` call will get all the `segment_list` elements (for the current `road_section`), you will have to limit the second inner loop to one iteration instead of `j < listaSegmentos.getLength()` or don't use a loop at all and do something like this:

```
if(listaSegmentos.getLength()>=1) {
    Node nodeseg = listaSegmentos.item(0);
    if (nodeseg.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element el = (Element) nodeseg;
        System.out.println("\nSegment id : " + el.getAttribute("id"));
        System.out.println("height : " + el.getElementsByTagName("height").item(0).getTextContent().replaceAll("\"", ""));
        System.out.println("number_vehicles : " + el.getElementsByTagName("number_vehicles").item(0).getTextContent().trim());
    }
}
```

The same goes for the first inner loop which has its condition set to `i < 1`

Comment: So u are saying that i dont need to use , item(i).getChildNodes() from ("segment_list"), .. i only need a loop and after i use getElementsByTagName("segment_list") and then there is another inner loop .. like that?  ... Sorry for all about that question i'm a little bit confused, cause i wouldn't exepect something like this

Comment: Thanks a lot! now i understand what u mean and the done its done ;)